# How to merge source code from Vault to TFS 2008

Tags: version-control, tfs, merge, sourcegear-vault

I am looking into merging our source control provider and bug tracking software to Team Foundation Server 2008.  We currently have SourceGear Vault as our source control provider and OnTime for our bug tracking software.  Both currently meet our needs however as we are growing it seems that TFS is a more likely candidate for our company.  It would have been nice if Microsoft had developed a merge tool so that we could get all of our source code into this new system including all the history.

As of now I can get all of our bug tracking items into the system through a csv import and I can also get the latest version of the source code into the system.

Is there an easy way or a toolkit that can be used in merging all of our source code with history from SourceGear Vault to TFS 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [TFS Migration and Syncronization toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/MigrationSyncToolkit).  This is an open source project developed by Microsoft for people doing this type of thing.  That said I usually recommend keeping the old system around for the history rather than importing as people usually have a better experience that way rather than going through the pain of import.

Comment: I have tried looking at this toolkit, however it doesn't appear that it was written for TFS 2008.

Comment: V1.1 definitely was - take a look at the release notes http://www.codeplex.com/MigrationSyncToolkit/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Release%20Notes

Comment: The release notes still don't have good documentation on how to even get started with that tool.  If SourceGear can create a migration tool from TFS then TFS should be able to do the same.  I don't think that it should be a requirement for our developers to spend weeks on a migration project w/ a buggy  toolkit.

I love your blog by the way.  We would get a few Brian the Build Bunnies if we could only get our source code history imported into TFS.